# Seeking site to compare Autosomal DNA results from National Geographic and Ancestry?

Tags: autosomal-dna

My elder sister and brother had their DNA done with the 1st Genographic kit from National Geographic. Sadly, they both just recently passed away within 6 months of each other. My sister deceased:July 19/17 and brother:January 16/18. Our younger brother had his DNA done in January/18 through Ancestry, and I just had mine done in March/18 through Ancestry. Our tests confirmed that we are actually half siblings.

Is there a specific site where all of our results combined can be submitted to, from both National Geographic & Ancestry for analysis?

Answer (score 4):

I've been using Gedmatch which allows you to upload DNA profiles from various companies and compare anyone in their database. I've used 23andme. 
https://www.gedmatch.com/

Their new beta supports even more upload types (which looks to support National Geographic & Ancestry):
https://genesis.gedmatch.com/

[image]